# Gutenberg get block name

Tags: block-editor

I'm using a filter in the Block API to add a class name to a block's wrapper. I have to add the class name to a specific block, not all blocks.

I tried:

```
const addClassName = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {    
  return ( props, blockType ) => {      
    if ( blockType.name === 'myplugin/myblock' ) {
        return <BlockListBlock { ...props } className="test" />;
    }
    return <BlockListBlock { ...props } />
  }
}, 'addClassName' );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockListBlock', 'myplugin/add-class-name', addClassName );
```

The issue: `blockType.name` returns undefined. I also tried `getBlockType.name` and it also returns undefined. I also tried getting the block name of core blocks. For example `core/columns`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the props object we can get the block information. The object contains the `name` property you are looking for; this would be the code:

```
const addClassName = createHigherOrderComponent(BlockListBlock => {
    return props => {
        if (props.name === "myplugin/myblock") {
            return <BlockListBlock {...props} className="test" />;
        }
        return <BlockListBlock {...props} />;
    };
}, "addClassName");

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    "editor.BlockListBlock",
    "myplugin/add-class-name",
    addClassName
);
```

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected block name by using this `wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getSelectedBlock().name;` inside the block edit or save function. This is the answer of what your question title is saying.

By the way you can easily add class anywhere in the layout inside edit function so why are you hassling so much.

Comment: This is for a filter which is not added in the edit or save function.

Comment: Where did you find `getSelectedBlock`? it does not seem to be a gutenberg function.

Comment: It's a gutenberg function which gives you the name of block only if the block was selected. For confirmation on editor screen select any block, open your console and write the code and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use wp data api to get the default class name of your block like this:

```
const className = getBlockDefaultClassName("namespace/yourblockname");
```

**getBlockDefaultClassName** is from **wp.blocks** so you can import it:

```
import { getBlockDefaultClassName } from "@wordpress/blocks";
```

or

```
const { getBlockDefaultClassName } = wp.blocks;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me most everything in WP is more complicated than it needs to be.  If I want the name of a block type, why can't the name simply show up when I click on a block?

And now I am trying to simply copy and paste a block in order to copy its color scheme, and none of the color scheme attributes will copy. Further, I can no longer go to the parent (existing) block and read the colors; they do not show up, like the data seems to be gone, though the block still renders correctly on the live site.

Very frustrating.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/265593)